# Introduce size in mm when scaling edges

Tags: modeling

Good evening to everyone,

My question is simple but I'm unable to find the answer. I'd like to input the size in mm (or meters) when scaling an arista instead of instroducing the scale unit with the keyboard. Just to be more precise. Is this possible?

The exact issue is that I would like to scale the edge in the picture by introducing the exact mm but I can't find how to do it.
[image]

Thanks in advance.
Jaume

Comment: Just select your object and press N. A sidebar will open and then you can change your dimensions there.

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for your reply but seems not working. I'm inserting a face in a plane and I'd like to input the size in mm in the 4 new aristas. N menu only shows the median.

Comment: For the OP and others: *arista* is *edge* in Spanish.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Markus

Comment: If you enable **Edit Mesh Tools** in Preferences->add-ons, you can use *Set Edge Length* operation in the *Numbers Panel*: https://i.imgur.com/6O2EsgQ.png

Comment: I'm trying to change it this way but seems not working either. When I input my size there the edge goes to the moon!

Comment: Perhaps because you don't specify `mm` so Blender guesses the base unit `m` which is 1000 times more than what you want.